# There is not such a file called "SDL2.h"

Tags: c++, sdl

I run KDE Neon 20.04 and whenever i try to run this command block in Sublime Text i get this error.

```
#include "SDL2.h"
#include "SDL2_image"
#include <iostream.h>
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    std::cout << "Yay" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

SDL2.h there is no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

You have to install SDL development libraries first. You can install it using the command `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev`.

You are also including sdl headers wrong.

This is the correct way.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
```

Comment: The `SDL2/` part shouldn't be necessary. This directory is supposed to be added to the include path (e.g. if you get compiler flags from `pkg-config`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Under normal case the compiler only includes `/user/include` and `/user/local/include`. But I consider my way better since it hints what package the header belongs to. It will be helpful when you have more dependencies in a project.